# What to get the parser tree of a compiler which is written using Lex and Yacc program?

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I have written a program using Lex and Yacc.I want to know how to get the parser tree of that using this program.Can anyone please give me the code to get it? I have used gcc lex.yy.c
y.tab.c -o project.exe

Answer (score 3):

Lex/Yacc don't build trees by themselves, they only execute code *you* supply when a certain rule matches. This means it's quite flexible, but it also means it's up to you to write tree-building code.

Luckily, building trees is not very complicated. Check out [this link](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs211/ho/node8.html) for an example you can use. The trick is that you can use yacc's semantic values (`$$` and friends) to pass up tree nodes:

```
input  : exp ';'               {do_something_with($1);}
       ;

exp    : '+' term              {$$ = $2;}
       | '-' term              {$$ = make_operator(NULL, '~', $2);}
       | term                  {$$ = $1;}
       | exp '+' term          {$$ = make_operator($1, '+', $3);}
       | exp '-' term          {$$ = make_operator($1, '-', $3);}
       ;

term   : factor                {$$ = $1;}
       | term '*' factor       {$$ = make_operator($1, '*', $3);}
       | term '/' factor       {$$ = make_operator($1, '/', $3);}
       ;

factor : number                {$$ = make_number($1);}
       | variable              {$$ = make_variable($1);}
       | '(' exp ')'           {$$ = $2;}
       ;
```

You'll obviously define your own functions for making the actual nodes. Again, check out the link for an example.